# Get the response from UIWebview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I am implementing an application.In that i am using the loadWithhtmstring: method to load the html in  web-view using this html, i am sending the data to server after executing that method,server returns the html. So my doubt is how to get that response html.

Answer (score 6):

Inside webViewdidFinishLoad delegate you can add

```
NSString *html = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: 
                                         @"document.body.innerHTML"];
```

It will return you html content in a NSString...

Comment: This will returns html whatever i sent to that webview.But i need whatever server sent as response.

Comment: response has a type..if you are getting html in return then that is your response...if you are getting JSON then we are in different zone..

Comment: Right, what do we do if JSON?

Comment: do we still use "document.body.innerHTML", for a response with a content-type:application/json, to get the json?